# Unable to Post rich text editor content in live server?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I am using ck editor , and i can successfully post the ckeditor content in my local server. But my live server is refused to post the rich text [ html ]content ? Please tell me the issue ? 
Is there any settings in php.ini ?actually my server is a shared hosting server with safe_mode is ON, Currently settings files are not available ,  I can post the content only if there is no html tags inside the editor. example : I can post the content 'I LOVE YOU' , but i cannot post the content

```
'<p><b>I LOVE YOU</b></p>.
```

Please tell me whats the issue? I also tried using ajax , but no choice , see my ajax code below,

```
function fajax(base){

    var ed = editor.getData();
    var url = "certificate/save_text"
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "data="+ed,
            url : url,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
    });
}
```

if the value of 'ed' is normal text then my code is success , but if the value is any html , then its return nothing without showing any error , please tell me the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similiar problem with the tinyMCE Editor recently.
When sending the data with ajax, try not to assemble the POST-data as string by yourself. Let jquery do it instead:

```
var ed = editor.getData();
var postData = {"data" : ed};
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            url : url,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
    });
```

This solved the problem for us.

Comment: var postData = ["data" : ed];
this is error , anyway the problem is not in ajax , even in php , it is not posting any html values , anybody please help me.

Comment: my bad: postData must be object, not array, edited the answer therefor. In our case the problem was the encoding of the html-code created by the editor that got mashed up by building the post-data string on our own, we also faced the problem with using standard-request instead of ajax, but as that is not a use case for us we sticked with the ajax-method. Since we are doing it as in my answer, the data is sent as wanted. Maybe you give it a try with the edited code?

Comment: No Luck my friend. Actually my code is working in my local server and in any other live servers except the current one I am using. The code in php , jquey , ajax all working in other servers . I am facing problems only in this server . Whenever i add any html tag < > , then my posted array is empty . I can't find whats the error ? Anybody Please tell me  wht's the error at least ?

Comment: actually there is no way php strips html-tags on its own without you explictily doing it, as far as I know. Did you debug your requests, using firebug and the like? Is there a chance to see this error in production?

Comment: debugged , but still not showing any error ,But finally i found a way, i know it is the problem of html tags , . I encoded the editor data using encodeurl , and then send as ajax post . Now its working but , i dont know whats the real issue of this server ,

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code,

see my code below, –

```
function fajax(status,base){
            var ed = editor.getData();
            cId = $("#eventD").val();
            var edd = encodeURI(ed); 
            var postData = {"data" : edd};
      var url = base+"certificate/save_text/"+cId+"/"+status; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,//"data="+ed,
                url : url,
                success: function(msg){
                                alert(msg); }); }
```